# How to let users let only view and create their Business Accounts and Contacts in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Restriction Groups are only for Customers and Vendors ! Not for Business Accounts ! I want to give access of Business Accounts and Contacts to specific users (Account Managers) who are External Sales Representatives !

On access to Business Accounts in Customer Management, the user is able to view and insert all Business Accounts and Contacts in the All Records Tab. Is it Customization the only solution ??

Answer (score 0):

The requested behavior can not be achieved without a customization. Let me suggest to submit a support case or a customization request for Acumatica to look into the possibility to customize Business Accounts and Contacts to add support for restriction groups.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way that i have done it, you can create a duplicate screen of the default generic inquiries for Contacts,Business account, customers and thru user access role grant access to the desired screens with desired permissions and filter does screens by workgroups or owners of the accounts.